# USA hockey rule - Cross Checking

Tags: ice-hockey

Can a player get a 2 and 10 for cross checking?

Or just a 2 or 5/10?0€

Comment: The question is perfectly clear if one is remotely familiar with penalties in ice hockey. The idiom used is extremely common, and the brevity does not detract from the completeness of the question.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can either get 2, 5, or 5+10. You cannot receive 2+10, 2+5, or 2+5+10.

For physical fouls such as cross checking, the ref can either give a 2 minute minor, or a 5 minute major, or a 5 minute major with an automatic 10 minute game misconduct for injury. In USA hockey rules, the 5+10 is given if the player is injured as a result of the crosscheck.

It is important to note that the 10 minute is a game misconduct, not just misconduct, so the player is automatically ejected for the rest of the game, even after the 10 minutes expire, and suspended for their next game.

Source:
https://www.usahockeyrulebook.com/page/show/1084653-rule-609-cross-checking